# Изменение текста внутри блока при наведении

Tags: css, hover

Есть блок и как меняется блок-ссылка при наведении:

```css
.article2:hover {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #e3e3e3;
  background-color: #F7FEFF;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 280px;
  height: 140px;
  border-radius: 17px;
}
```

```html
<a href="/faq" title="FAQ">
  <div class="article2">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/33ff99/555555?text=Logo" alt="текст" />
    <for>FAQ</for>
  </div>
</a>
```

Но я не могу понять как сделать, чтобы менялся и текст, который находится внутри этого блока:

```
`<for>FAQ</for>`
```

Например, изменился его размер, цвет и расположение. Пробовал по-разному, но не выходит, поскольку изменения начинают касаться и блока.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.article2 for + for, .article2:hover for { display: none; }
.article2 for, .article2:hover for + for { display: block; }
```

```html
<a href="/faq" title="FAQ">
  <div class="article2">
    <img src="/images/logo.png" alt="текст">
    <for>ABC</for><for>DEF</for>
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.article-container {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #fff;
}

.article {
    color: #000;
}
.text{
    
}
.text-hover {     
    visibility: hidden;       
}
.article-container:hover .text{
    display: none;
}
.article-container:hover .text-hover {    
    visibility: visible;    
}
```

```html
<a href="/faq" title="FAQ" class="article-container">
    <div class="article">
        <img src="/images/logo.png" alt="текст">
        <span class="text">FAQ</span>
        <span class="text-hover">text text</span>
    </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Ну, во-первых, оборачивать блочные элементы `<div>` в строчные элементы `<a>` это плохо. должно быть наоборот. Во-вторых, есть несколько способов 
 сделать это, [jquery](https://jquery.com/) или использовать псевдо атрибуты `after` или `before`. Я подготовил [фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/mt77g9wr/) в котором есть примеры использования.

Comment: Во-первых, в html5 `a` не считается строчным и помещать в него div'ы разрешено. Во-вторых, код должен быть непосредственно в ответе (в виде сниппета).